# Break up a row of data into multiple rows defined by another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I'm running population models, where the program spits out values for each year I run the models for. Populations can become extinct, others persist for the full run of the model. I do this for many iterations of the  model and I want to end up with a data frame where the rows represent iterations, and the columns are years. The data manipulation side of things is happening through R.

I obtain two datasets from the program, where one is the values for each year for the population (if it was still alive). It does this for all the iterations and creates a single text file with values separated by semi colons and there is no differentiation as to which value belongs to which iteration. The other dataset represents if the population became extinct at any point for each iteration. This is in a csv and in one column. Here is some simple sample data of what it looks like.

```
#Create example data frame of values
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 7, nrow = 1))
df[1,] <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

#This is the year the population became extinct.
extinct <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 4))
extinct[,1] <- c(3, 2, NA, 2)
```

My problem is that the program text output does not put NAs in the years where the population is now extinct, so when converting the string of values to columns, there are values in the wrong position as all cells have been filled. E.g

```
df.new <- as.data.frame(matrix(df[1,], byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))
names(df.new) <- c("Year 1", "Year 2", "Year 3")

print(df.new)

  Year 1 Year 2 Year 3
1      1      2      3
2      4      5      6
3      7      1      2
```

The above resulting data frame doesn't account for the fact that some of the cells should contain NAs. The extinct vector dictates at what point a new row should be started, with the values vector being broken up accordingly. I.e. The correct matrix should actually look like this as defined by the 'extinct' data frame:

```
  Year 1 Year 2 Year 3
1      1      2      NA
2      3      NA     NA
3      4      5      6
4      7      NA     NA
```

If I were to do this manually and out loud, I would say "In iteration 1, the population became extinct at year 3. So I take the remaining values, fill until column 2, and the remaining columns become NA. In iteration 2, the population became extinct in year 2. So I take the remaining values, fill until column 1, and the remaining columns become NA. In iteration 3, there were no extinctions. So I take the remaining values, fill all the columns... etc."

My real data frame actually will have 20 columns and 1000 rows. I have to do this for many datasets and changing it manually will take hours.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to give a more robust explanation of your issue

Comment: Echoing the other comment, your exact issue is a bit unclear - how do you want to update the data frame with the extinction periods? Also, I think you would benefit from keeping a consistent type in the data frame columns for year 1/2/3 (as in your df example). You could set the column names using the ```names()```function, and each column will then contain only numbers. You ought to be able to set them to NA or 0 using a lookup.

Comment: What is unclear is how does the extinct vector relate to the values vector. The transformations of these vectors into matrices and then dataframes do not shed light on this.

Comment: I've tried rephrasing my original post. Hopefully this provides some clarity. 

I've also removed the header names from the example data as it's distracting from the main problem I'm having, which is reorganising the one row into multiple rows of different column lengths.